# Proof Verification: The polynomial $f(x) = (x+1)^n-x^n-1$ has a root of multiplicity 2 if and only if $n \equiv 1 \pmod 6$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Proof Verification: The polynomial $f(x) = (x+1)^n-x^n-1$ has a root of multiplicity 2 if and only if $n \equiv 1 \mod 6$

Let $r$ be a root, real or complex, of multiplicity 2 of $f(x)$. Then, by the factor theorem, $f(x) = (x-r)^2q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. Differentiating, $f'(x) = 2(x-r)q(x) + (x-r)^2q(x).$ Therefore, $f(r) = f'(r) = 0$.

We have $f(r) = (r+1)^n-r^n-1 = 0$ **[1]** and $f'(r) = 0 \implies (r+1)^{n-1}-r^{n-1} = 0$ **[2]**.

Let $r=e^{i\theta}$. From [2], $|r| = |r+1| = 1$ so $r = -1/2 + i\sqrt3/2 = e^{i\pi/3}$

Substituting [2] into [1], we get $r^{n-1}(r+1)-r^n=1 \implies r=\sqrt[n-1]1$. Then $(e^{i\pi/3})^{n-1} = 1$ so we finally get $(n-1)\pi/3 = 2m\pi \implies n = 6m+1.$

$QED $

Edit: any tips on my MathJax?

Comment: Why does $r=r+1$ (You can actually get this) imply that $r=e^{\frac{i \pi}{3}}$? I was working on this problem right now and I got every result you’ve listed but I can’t be sure why, for instance, $r=e^{\frac{i \pi}{k}}$ isn’t possible for $k\not=3$? I am unable to show this right now and I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Oh never mind! I realize what to do now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should be $e^{2i\pi/3}$ not $e^{i\pi/3}$.